# Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Где нужны запятые в предложении: "Не так в сущности важно кто это"? И вообще "в сущности" выделяется запятыми?

Comment: @Claire, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3):

Не так, в сущности, важно, кто это.

СПП с придаточным изъяснительным, наречие в качестве опорного слова.

В сущности (в сущности говоря) - вводное слово.

Answer (score 0):

Ответ Веры точен. Объясняю.
"в сущности" - вводное слово, можно убрать без ущерба для смысла. "кто это" - придаточ. предл., сказуемое опущено, но явно понимается: кто он есть.